# Mysql 5.1 my.cnf not in /etc/mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I installed mysql-server-5.1 on my Ubuntu server using `apt-get install mysql-server`, but i cant find my.cnf file.

It is not in `/etc/mysql`.
In `/etc/mysql` i have only:

```
conf.d
\-mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
debian-start
sebian.cnf
```

I have tried uninstalling/installing mysql multiple times, but still nothing.

Also, when installing mysql, i get messages like this: (i have installed `dialog`)

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
```

Comment: Try to find it: find / -name my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy one from `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.1/examples/` . Rename it to `my.cnf` and place in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

and about `dialog` , set your `TERM` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED : Sometimes the my.cnf is located in just the /etc directory.

/etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

If you installed mysql-server, it should have installed mysql-common which includes that file.  I'm guessing that something failed in that installation, disk out of space, interrupted for whatever reason.

```
apt-get --reinstall install mysql-common
```

which is a predependency for mysql-server-5.1

If it comes up with errors, try:

```
dpkg --reconfigure -a
```

or

```
apt-get -f install
```